# Let $n$ be a positive integer relatively prime with $10$. Prove that the digits of hundreds of $n^{20}$ is even.

Tags: prime-numbers, divisibility, prime-factorization

Let $n$ be a positive integer relatively prime with $10$. Prove that the hundreds digit of $n^{20}$ is even.

I know this has something to do with $\bmod 1000$, I'm just not sure how to write a proof on it. Thank you!

Comment: the hundred$\color{red}{th}$ digit or the digits of hundreds (the third digit starting from the right). Surely the second...

Comment: I believe its hundreds as in 100 (the place with a 1)

Comment: Yes it has something to do with computation mod $1000$. Please, work by checking the property on low values of $n$, then try a recurrence on $n$ and show us your work.

Comment: Hint: $n$ doesn't have to be co-prime to $10$; it just has to be odd.

Comment: $(50n+k)^{20}=1000m+k^{20}$, so we need to only check for $1\le k\le 49$

Answer (score 2):

Note that $x^{20} \equiv_{25} 1$ and $x^{20} \equiv_8 1$.
So $x^{20} \equiv_{25×8} 1$. Can you finish from here.

Comment: And if $x \equiv_{10} 5$, then $x^{20}\equiv_{25} 0$ and $x \equiv_8 1$. Finish in the same fashion as above.

Comment: Have you seen that the OP has made no effort: I asked him to check it on the first values of $n$, to try recurrence... no echo. Typical of somebody waiting the work to be done by others...

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative which does not use totient function as in Mike's answer, instead it relies heavily on the binomial expansion (used three times in this proof).

Notice that for $a\in\{0,1,\cdots,9\}$ and $b>0$

$x^{20}=(a+10b)^{20}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{20} \binom{20}{k}a^{20-k}10^k=a^{20}+200(\cdots)$

This is because $200\mid 10^k\binom{20}{k}$ for $k\ge 1$

- for $k=1$ this is $10\times 20=200$
- for $k\ge 2$ then $100\mid 10^k$ and $2\mid \binom{20}{k}$

As a consequence we only have to examine values $a=1,3,7,9$ because if a number ends with $a=0,2,4,5,6,8$ it is either divisible by $2$ or $5$ which is not possible since $\gcd(x,10)=1$.

- $1^{20}\equiv 1\pmod{200}$
- $3^{20}=81^{5}\equiv (80+1)^5\equiv 1^5+200(\cdots)\equiv 1\pmod{200}$
- $9^{20}=3^{20}\,3^{20}\equiv 1\pmod{200}$
- $7^{20}=2401^{5}\equiv (2400+1)^5\equiv 1^5+200(\cdots)\equiv 1\pmod{200}$

This means $x^{20}=200y+001$ so the hundreds digit is even.